# How do you run rosbag2 in ROS2 Crystal?

Tags: ros2, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS2 Crystal on Ubuntu 18.04.  I've installed the ros-crystal-rosbag2 package, but am not sure how to run it.  From the [Github readme](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2) it looks like this should add a verb to the ROS2 command, but when I run:

```
ros2 bag record -a
```

I get the following error:

```
usage: ros2 [-h] Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage. ...
ros2: error: argument Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage.: invalid choice: 'bag' (choose from 'daemon', 'extension_points', 'extensions', 'launch', 'lifecycle', 'msg', 'multicast', 'node', 'param', 'pkg', 'run', 'service', 'srv', 'topic')
```

How do I run rosbag2 in Crystal?

Thanks,

David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317262/how-do-you-run-rosbag2-in-ros2-crystal?/) by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2019-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please make sure to follow the debian instructions correctly:
https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2#debian-packages

So in particular, the package you installed does only support the API for `rosbag2`. The actual command line verb gets added by `ros-crystal-ros2bag`.

---

Originally posted by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) with karma: 643 on 2019-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) on 2019-03-05**:
Thanks.  That fixed it.  Having a ros2bag and rosbag2 package is somewhat confusing.  Is there any documentation on the difference in the two?